# Search a list while typing in textbox VueJS 2

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I have a list of users from an array. And I want to filter them based on the search box(name) at the top. I saw that there are filters in VueJS 1. But not available in VuesJS 2. How can achieve this in VueJS 2

```
<input type="text" v-model="search"/>   
<div class="row profile" v-for="customer in customers">
 <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3"><img :src="customer.profile_pic" class="profile-pic" /></div>
 <div class="col-md-8"><h4 class="name">{{customer.name}}</h4></div>
</div>
<script>
    data: function () {
      return{
        search: '',
        customers: [
          { id: '1', name: 'user 1', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'ab@gmail.com', phone:'+91959657248', unread:'0' },
          { id: '2', name: 'user 2', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'abcd@gmail.com', phone:'+919456664023', unread:'0' },
          { id: '3', name: 'user 3', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'test@gmail.com', phone:'+919566565065', unread:'0' },
          { id: '4', name: 'user 4', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'sample@gmail.com', phone:'+916466004566', unread:'0' }
        ]
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have done this by having my property "array" with the data elements and a computed property (array as well) with the filtered elements.
The HTML renders the filtered elements. I have a property bound to the text box.
For simplicity, something like this:

```
data: function () {
      return{
        search: '',
        customers: [
          { id: '1', name: 'user 1', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'ab@gmail.com', phone:'+91959657248', unread:'0' },
          { id: '2', name: 'user 2', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'abcd@gmail.com', phone:'+919456664023', unread:'0' },
          { id: '3', name: 'user 3', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'test@gmail.com', phone:'+919566565065', unread:'0' },
          { id: '4', name: 'user 4', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'sample@gmail.com', phone:'+916466004566', unread:'0' }
        ]
},
computed:
{
    filteredCustomers:function()
    {
        var self=this;
        return this.customers.filter(function(cust){return cust.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase())>=0;});
    }
}
```

Bind your HTML to filteredCustomers. You should now have a reactive HTML based on what you type on search. That "filter" method is native JavaScript for arrays, I lower-cased both values to make it case insensitive.

Here's a working example in fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkmmhf5y/1/

Edit: Added fiddle and code corrections in computed property

Comment: What cust represents in filter function?

Comment: current element of the array...it can be called any name, JavaScript will call the function passing each element as parameter

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez I suggest you add the code on how to "bind your HTML to filteredCustomers". It'll be helpful.

Comment: @dipoisola I added a fiddle and corrected some of the code. Thanks.

Comment: What if I need to filter async data?

Comment: Thanks @NelsonRodriguez your fiddle helped me a lot. Although I had to do it with lodash filter

Comment: @Tiago working with Async data will require a different approach (in my opinion) which is to have a 'watch' over the search term, make an ajax call to the server to get the data and then put that data in the array that is used to display the info. The watch might require a "debounce" function so that you don't make a request on every single character typed, but instead after a few milliseconds after the user stops typing

Comment: If we want to initialise powertip in computed, how do we do that?

Comment: @MohdAnas Sorry, I'm not familiar with powertip and if it can work with Vue data bindings

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez, No Problem I have used vue-tippy and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Filters has been [removed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2756) in vuejs 2. As suggested by @azamat-sharapov, you can have reusable filters using one of following 3 ways:

> How can I do it in 2.0?
>
> - Mixin
> - Separate module with method
> - Separate module with computed prop function

A simple implementation of filter in vuejs 2 can be using a computed property which can call a method to get filtered list. in the method you can pass list, query and it can return the [filtered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) list. see following code and working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gewsu3yd/). Following are generic functions, which can be moved to mixin or module and can be re-used in multple components.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    customers: [
          { id: '1', name: 'user 1', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'ab@gmail.com', phone:'+91959657248', unread:'0' },
          { id: '2', name: 'user 2', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'abcd@gmail.com', phone:'+919456664023', unread:'0' },
          { id: '3', name: 'user 3', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'test@gmail.com', phone:'+919566565065', unread:'0' },
          { id: '4', name: 'user 4', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'sample@gmail.com', phone:'+916466004566', unread:'0' }
        ],
    columns: {
      id : {
        displayname : "id",
        sortorder : 1
      },
      name : {
        displayname : "name",
        sortorder : 1
      },
      email : {
        displayname : "email",
        sortorder : 1
      }
    },
    query: '',
   },
  computed: {
    tableFilter: function () {
        return this.findBy(this.customers, this.query, 'name')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findBy: function (list, value, column) {
      return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item[column].includes(value)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: what the use for columns here? Sorry I'm a newbie in VueJS

Comment: @GijoVarghese That is just for display purpose in HTML, not related to filter logic.

Comment: Can you please remove that for me? Pls? I tried, but the whole thing just crashed

Comment: How can I search from paginated result ?
What if being searched thing is not on first page of pagination ?

Answer (score 1):

**This method worked good for me**

```
computed: {
   filteredList() {
     return this.postList.filter(post => {
       var vm = this;
       return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(vm.search.toLowerCase())
     })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by Nathan but I think this would work better and it eliminates the need for the `var self = this` assignment. It will also keep eslint happy as the Vue eslint plugin frowns upon using `indexOf` when looking for existence. Here it is:

```js
data: function () {
      return{
        search: '',
        customers: [
          { id: '1', name: 'user 1', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'ab@gmail.com', phone:'+91959657248', unread:'0' },
          { id: '2', name: 'user 2', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'abcd@gmail.com', phone:'+919456664023', unread:'0' },
          { id: '3', name: 'user 3', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'test@gmail.com', phone:'+919566565065', unread:'0' },
          { id: '4', name: 'user 4', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png', email:'sample@gmail.com', phone:'+916466004566', unread:'0' }
        ]
},
computed:
{
    filteredCustomers () {
      return this.customers.filter((customer) => {
        return customer.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks @Kelvin Omereshone

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!-- Searching Bar Start -->
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <span style="float:left; margin:0 10px; padding-top:5px; color:black;">Search:</span>
        <input v-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter users by Queue" style="width:30%;">
            </div>
        <!-- Searching Bar End -->

<td style="width:25%;cursor:pointer;color: blue;" class="tablecolthree" @click="sortbytotal('pending_duration_day')">Pedning Duration <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>

        return {
            search:'',
            dupsearch:'',
            currentSort:'pending_duration_day',
            currentSortDir:'asc',
        }
        methods: {
        sortbytotal:function(s) {
            this.dupsearch='sort';
            this.search='';
            if(s === this.currentSort) {
                this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
            }
            this.currentSort = s;
        },
            date(e){
            if(this.stdate){
                var fromdate = [];
                this.loading = true;
                fromdate.push(moment(this.stdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                this.showstart = moment(this.stdate).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
                axios.get('/open-ticket-detail?date='+fromdate).then(response => {
                    this.openticketdetail = response.data;
                    this.loading = false;
                    //console.log(this.openticket);
                })
            }
            e.preventDefault();   
        }
        },
        computed:{
        sortedCats:function() 
        {
            var self=this;
            if(self.search!=''){
               this.dupsearch='';
            }

            if(this.dupsearch=='sort'){
                return this.openticketdetail.open_tickets.sort((a,b) => {
                    let modifier = 1;
                    if(this.currentSortDir === 'asc') modifier = -1;
                    if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
                    if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
                    return 0;
                });
            }
            return this.openticketdetail.open_tickets.filter(function(openticket){return openticket.queue_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase())>=0;});
        },
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
`computed: {
    filteredResources(){
         return this.Surveyors.filter((surveyor)=>{
         return surveyor.Name.toLowerCase().match(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());  
         })
      }
    }`
```

/*Surveyors is data table name and surveyor is its index like in your example you are having customer in customers*/